# spawning a process in ruby, capturing stdout, stderr, getting exist status

Tags: ruby

I want to run an executable from a ruby rake script, say `foo.exe`

I want the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` outputs from `foo.exe` to be written directly to the console I'm running the rake task from.

When the process completes, I want to capture the exit code into a variable. How do I achieve this?

I've been playing with `backticks`, `process.spawn`, `system` but I cant get all the behaviour I want, only parts

**Update:** I'm on Windows, in a standard command prompt, not cygwin

Comment: Which part of this isn't covered by `Kernel#system`?

Comment: I know that `Net-SSH` pure ruby lib which works with openSSL has such functionality - `exec` method of it's `channel` returns array of `[stdout, stderr, exit_code, exit_signal]`. Maybe you can use it somehow...

Comment: Perhaps you should list out your problems with each of those commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system) gets the `STDOUT` behaviour you want. It also returns `true` for a zero exit code which can be useful.

`$?` is populated with information about the last `system` call so you can check that for the exit status:

```
system 'foo.exe'
$?.exitstatus
```

I've used a combination of these things in [`Runner.execute_command`](https://github.com/zopaUK/bozo/blob/86beb53e7b78d5f01086da4d5e2839642b5672dc/lib/bozo/runner.rb#L29) for an example.

Comment: turned out i didnt need STDERR so I cant verify that this _does_ handle it, but it works for my needs

Answer (score 2):

backticks will get `stdout` captured into resulting string

`foo.exe` suggests you are running windows - do you have anything like cygwin installed? if you run your script within unixy shell you can do this:

```
result = `foo.exe 2>&1`
status = $?.exitstatus
```

quick googling says this should also work in native windows shell but i can't test this assupmtion